# Akeeba subscription component menu is not working

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1, joomla-component

Hope you are having good health.

**My Joomla version is 3.1** . I have installed `Akeeba` component for subscription functionality. My Component is working fine except its subscription menu link on the front end.

**What is problem:** In my case, when the user logs into the site and clicks on the subscription link under his my account menu then It displays the white blank page instead of showing the subscription list.

**What I did:** I have already set "all of my subscription" for the subscriptions 
menu from the back-end. I have not put any custom code from my end.
I have checked error log and found no error there.  I have cleared cache too but no solution.

Please help me to resolve this iff any one faced this problem and resolved.

Comment: Please turn on the error_reporting from the configuration and check whether it shows something on the page.

Comment: I have already done but it is just blank white page

Comment: Maybe it's not compatible with Joomla 3.1. Whatever the case Joomla 3.1. is outdated and insecure. You should upgrade. Also there is a dedicated Joomla site in StackExchange for Joomla Administration and Development. Check there: [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com).